# Wireshark shows device on my network sending me TCP packets

Tags: networking, wireshark

I downloaded Wireshark to understand better TCP handshake and found something I thought was interesting.[image]

It's showing packets from 192.168.100.4 (that's my private IP) and 192.168.100.8 (don't know what device this is but it's clearly on the same network as me.) is there an explanation for this. why would my computer be communicating with another device on my network directly?

these TCP and UDP connections are continuous. but there are also MDNS packets being sent from 192.168.100.8 but not to my computer.
[image]

This is a home Wifi. There are a few other devices (my family) on the network. when I log in to the router it says that the device type is android-dhcp-7.0 (probably means an android phone that doesn't help me I'm the only one who doesn't use an android) and hostname android-2fdb2dd839097089. I don't know whether to check the mac address of each device on the network but even then still I wouldn't know how these TCP connections are being created especially if it's a phone.

can anyone suggest possible reasons these connections would be happening automatically? I have many networks on my wifi but this seems to be the only one having a TCP connection with me.

#### Update:

some of the TCP connections to 192.168.100.8 show up like this.
[image]

Comment: (1) look at the data in the frames and see if it is recognizable (2) see what process/program handles this socket (and data) with `netstat -tno` on Windows (or `-tnb` if elevated) or `netstat -tnp` on some Linux, `ss -tnp` on some other Linux, and other variations on other Unixes.

Answer (score -2):

MDNS stands for **M**ulticast **DNS** it works as follows.
If a device needs to get an ipaddress for a domain (example stackoverflow.com) it don't request it from the router instead it ask an other device on the network (in this case your computer).

Check this [Nameresolution in wireshark](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/37680/can-wireshark-automatically-resolve-the-ip-address-into-host-names/) to resolve your ip addresses in wireshark.

Can you provide the content of the packages?

Comment: I'm not really worried about the MDNS that's not between the 192.168.100.4 and 192.168.100.8. its the TCP  connection that I'm concerned about.

Comment: What is the content of the TCP package?